# How can I shop for someone living in Germany, from a German website, whilst paying from USA?

Tags: germany, shipping

I have family that lives in Germany and I would like to send the kids Christmas gifts. I do not want to ship from the US to Germany, I would rather shop from German websites for quicker shipping time and fewer fees. I tried going on amazon.de but it does not keep me logged into my Amazon account, and the google translator did not work for the site (I cannot read German). I found some other websites such as https://www.fnp.com/germany/gifts but it does not seem to be geared towards children. Any recommendations for online shops that I can purchase children's gifts in Germany and have shipped within Germany but pay from the USA? Thank you

Comment: Honestly, I think this is going to be a real challenge without being able to read German, but I hope somebody comes through. There are certainly enough German expats living in English-speaking countries that I could see the demand. You might consider using a European VPN to sort out the Amazon.de logging-out problem.

Comment: @Marky1298 This explanation seems helpful, if you’ve not already seen it https://transferwise.com/us/blog/buying-from-amazon-in-a-different-country It mentions “Just as a general note, though it may appear that you’ll be creating a new account, if you use the same email and password as your other Amazon account, your account info will transfer to the new Amazon account.”

Comment: If the question is about Amazon specifically, that's probably a tech support issue (i.e. off topic for this site). But Amazon seems to be fine with letting you changing your country and language to pretty much whatever you want (including English in Germany, although it looks like it's machine translated). There's a country flag next to the search bar and also at the bottom of the page. A US credit card should also be fine (for Amazon at least, some other sites may reject that to prevent fraud or tax/legal complications).

Comment: I'm surprised you weren't able to use Amazon.de.  You can change the language to English.  I use the same Amazon account for Amazon.com and Amazon.de.  It's strange that this didn't work for you.  I would suggest you try calling the help line (where you'll find English speakers if you ask), but I guess if you can't get the language to be in English in the first place, you won't know where to find the help line.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: You can log onto amazon.de with your amazon.com account. There you can switch your language to English.

Comment: I've verified this. Would you update your post with the 'longer' answer, maybe with a screenshot, please?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the product is also available in Germany, ordering on the us Amazon site, with delivery in Germany, it will be sent from the nearest depository in Europe.

They will also probably apply the local VAT, since the recipient is the final consumer. This will also avoid possible customs tarifs and overseas delivery costs.

You should see this as the last step of the purchase before the buying transaction has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the US. I have had success ordering for a relative in the Netherlands using my US credit card and Google Chrome to translate on the fly, in my case from the Dutch eBay or Amazon websites into English.